# Why does this query string work in Access but not C#?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have this bit of code:

```
conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=c:\\myDB.accdb");
conn.Open();

sql = string.Format("SELECT Version FROM tblVersions where [FUL Flag] = 'Y'");
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds);
dt = ds.Tables[0];

if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
{
    tV.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();    //only looking for the first result
}
else
{
    tV.Text = "no match";
}
```

When I run it, it doesn't return any results. However if I copy the `SELECT` statement and paste it right into a query window in Access, it does find results. Here's what I paste into Access:

```
SELECT Version FROM tblVersions where [FUL Flag] = 'Y'
```

This returns many rows.

Am I missing a difference somewhere? Thanks!

EDIT: Found the solution .. I should be looking for

```
(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
```

instead of

```
(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
```

Since more than 1 row may be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that your statement of behaviour here:

> When I run it, it doesn't return any results.

means "the `TextBox` text is replaced with 'no match'". Is that right?

> This returns many rows.

Well that explains it. Look at your condition:

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
```

You're claiming there are *no* matches in every case unless there's *exactly one* match.

You probably want:

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
```

Comment: yeah i caught that right after posting my question. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 instead of ==1
```

Full example:

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    tV.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();    //only looking for the first result
}
else
{
    tV.Text = "no match";
}
```